# decryption_key filter in pyshark

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-3.6, wireshark, pyshark

I am able to decrypt network traffic in Wirehsark by importing the 'key' file in it. However, cannot implement it using pyshark. 
I came across the filter "decryption_key" in pyshark, but whenever I write: decryption_key="path_to_key", it doesn't work. I am relatively new in this field and just experimenting. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What protocol are we even decrypting? TLS? SSH? What version of the protocol?

Comment: We are decrypting TLSv1.3.

Comment: TLS1.3 support was recently added to Wireshark, so it won’t have made it into Pyshark yet.